# Open graph image doesn't show up

Tags: linkedin-api, facebook-opengraph, django-cms

Open graph image doesn't show up as a thumbnail when posting url on linkedin.

However the thumbnail works in the post inspector https://www.linkedin.com/post-inspector/ and after that it works on the linkedin.
Refreshing cache manually of every blog post is not an option(a lot of posts)

So my question is how to fix that and make open graph images work for every blog post without posting them first in the post inspector. What could be wrong with the website?